# oracle sql - get difference between 2 dates (sysdate minus the datevalue of a other table)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know the difference betweeen 2 dates.

I need something like this:
"sysdate minus the datevalue of a other table"

Currently I have something like this, but it's not working

```
SELECT something FROM myTable1 WHERE mydate >= sysdate-(SELECT latestExport FROM myTable2 WHERE id=1);
```

The 2nd select statement prints the date of the latest export. Example "27-JUL-21".

thanks for your help.

Comment: Sample data would be helpful (Not image!)

Comment: What means "not working"?

Comment: `DATE` is a reserved keyword, you cannot use it as column name.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you are right, i actually didn't use "date" as a column name. i just changed it for here so you won't see the actual column name. Sorry about that. I corrected it.

Comment: Could you provide us a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can not work. Because the result of

```
sysdate-(SELECT latestExport FROM myTable2 WHERE id=1)
```

is a decimal value. For example 5121.2 days difference between `SYSDATE` and `latestExport`  and you can not compare your Date value `mydate` with a decimal. This is the logic you used:

```
Is "25-10-2020" >= 5121.2 ?
```

You need to think again about the result you want to get from this query.